# Integer is printed out a different value from what it actually is?

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
int x = 435;
int y = x / 2 * 5;
```

If I calculate y by hand, I get a result of 1087.5. But when I print the integer y out, I get the result 1085. Why is this? Shouldn't it round to either 1088 or 1087?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of *integer arithmetic*:

```
int/int = int
```

So, `435/2` will be

```
435/2 = 217
```

And

```
217*5 = 1085
```

**What can you do?** Cast the values as you need:

```
int y = (int)((float)x / 2 * 5);
```

or if you want a real result, declare the variable `y` as `float`:

```
float y = (float)x / 2 * 5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe I didn't see that.

Comment: Or (at least in this case): multiply first, then divide.

Answer (score 2):

this saves in result of each part as an int

so

```
435 / 2 == 217
217 * 5 == 1085
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` value of `x/2=217` and `217 * 5 == 1085` is the reason

you are dividing `int` value `x` so result will be `int` value `(int/int=int)`

```
 x/2=217
```

Then

```
 217*5=1085
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int x = 435;
    double y = ((double) x / 2) * 5;
```

`y` cannot be int (or else you will lose precision). Moreover, `x / 2` will yield you an `integer` value, hence you need to cast it to `double` or `float`

Answer (score 0):

Java is using integer math, this

```
int x = 435;
int y = x / 2 * 5;
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = 435;
int y = x / 2; // <-- 217
y *= 5;        // <-- 1085
```

If you wanted to round the other way try,

```
int x = 435;
int y = (int) Math.round(((double) x / 2) * 5); // <-- 1088
```

Answer (score 0):

When you divide 435 by 2.
It stores 217 not 217.5 and hence after multiplying 217*5= 1085

You are trying to store a float value into INT and hence getting the truncated value.

Also,without brackets, the compiler will start to execute from LHS to RHS one by one according to priority of operator.

Your code

int x = 435;
int y = x / 2 * 5;

is actually performing the following operation.

1. Assigning    x = 435;
2. Dividing first  y = x / 2;             // This stores y= 217
3. And then it multiplies y=y*5;        // Finally y= 1085

Using int will truncate 217.5 into 217 and hence you are getting that answer.
Use double or float for storing the kind of answer you want

int x = 435;
double y = y=(x/2)*5

This will get you the required answer.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is correct as -:
435/2 = 217.5 since declared as int it is rounded off to 217
217*5 = 1085
which is the required answer.